# How to color the slices of amchart piechart?

Tags: c#, xaml, charts, styles, windows-phone

How do I color the individual slices of a piechart using the amcharting

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <chart:PieChart Height="300" Width="400"
                    TitleMemberPath="Title"
                    ValueMemberPath="Value">
        <chart:PieChart.DataSource>
            <local:PieDataCollection>
                <local:PieData Title="Democrat" Value="123"/>
                <local:PieData Title="Republic" Value="213"/>
                <local:PieData Title="independent" Value="123"/>
            </local:PieDataCollection>
        </chart:PieChart.DataSource>
    </chart:PieChart>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Never used it before, but any chance its like so: https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts/blob/master/QuickChartsSLApp/PieChart.xaml using the PieChart.Brushes syntax in XAML?

Comment: were you able to change the colors ?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.0 SDK.

Just add a collection of brushes into the PieChart structure.

**Using XAML**

```
<chart:PieChart Height="300" Width="400" TitleMemberPath="Title" ValueMemberPath="Value">
    <chart:PieChart.Brushes>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>  <!-- color item #1 -->
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/> <!-- color item #2 -->
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/> <!-- color item #3 -->
    </chart:PieChart.Brushes>                    
    <chart:PieChart.DataSource>        
        <local:PieDataCollection>
            <local:PieData Title="Democrat" Value="123"/>
            <local:PieData Title="Republic" Value="213"/>
            <local:PieData Title="independent" Value="123"/>
        </local:PieDataCollection>
    </chart:PieChart.DataSource>
</chart:PieChart>
```

**Using C#**

```
public void LoadColors()
{
    System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush red = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush();
    red.Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);

    System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush green = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush();
    green.Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00);

    System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush blue = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush();
    blue.Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);

    this.PieChart.Brushes.Add(red);    // add red
    this.PieChart.Brushes.Add(green);  // add green
    this.PieChart.Brushes.Add(blue);   // add blue

    this.PieChart.DataSource = Data;   // set the datasource
}
```